# How to print out result of all class

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name "Table1" with the following records of students.

```
student_id | Name | Math | English | Sience | Class
1            John   100    90        89       std two
2            Simon  100    100       100      std two
3            Irene  80     70        70       std two
```

I tried to output the AVG, Total of each student passmark, but I fail to out put the result of all class.

Example: for now the result is like this when I search.

```
student_id | Name | Math | English | Sience | Class    Average Total
1            John   100    90        89       std two  93      279
```

and when I search another student I get the desired answer, but when I search "std two" as class name I get the result of first student who has 1 student_id instead the all class.
The answer I want is like this or any format but should output result of all class.

```
student_id | Name | Math | English | Sience | Class    Average Total
1            John   100    90        89       std two  93      279 

student_id | Name | Math | English | Sience | Class    Average Total
2            Simon  100    100       100      std two  100     300

 student_id | Name | Math | English | Sience | Class    Average Total
 3            Irene  80     70        70       std two  73.3    220
```

This is my php code

```
<?php


 //include mysql connect
   $query='query';

   if (isset($_GET['query'])) 
{    
   $query=$_GET['query'];


      } 

    $min_length = 2;
   // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum   
  length  
   then


    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection



    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT *, AVG(math+english+science)/3 as  
  Average, (math+english+science)as Total from table1
     WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') or (`class` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or  
    die(mysql_error()); 

     // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query 
    is Hello
    // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use   
  `title`='$query'
    // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %'  
  ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'
    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
      // if query length is more or equal minimum length the

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) >= 0){
     // if one or more rows are returned do following


         // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into   
    array, while it's valid it does the loop

                  while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

//The echo table         


 echo "<table width='500' height='2' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
 echo"<tr><td>Id_number</td><td>Name</td><td>Math</td><td>English</td><td>Science</td>     
<td>Class</td><td>Average</td><td>Total</td>";
echo "<tr>"."<td>".$results["student_id"]."</td>"."<td>".$results["name"]."</td>"."   
<td>".$results["math"]."</td>"."<td>".$results["english"]."</td>"."  
<td>".$results["science"]."<td>".$results["class"]."<td>".$results["Average"]."</td>"." 
<td>".$results["Total"]."</td>"."</p>";
echo"</table>";  




        } 

    }   
             }


        }





    ?>
```

Comment: Don't call `AVG`. That's for averaging across rows, not averaging across columns. Just divide the total by 3 and that's the average.

Comment: [**Sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18bc1/4/1). [What AVG does?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: By the way, you may want to change `<php` to `<?php` actually let me rephrase that; you WILL want to change that.

Comment: Was anyone thrown by the weird syntax highlighting for a couple of seconds?

Comment: @DarylGill Yes me, hence my comment above ;-) that's why it's doing that. The OP left out the `?` in `<php`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
AVG(math+english+science)/3
```

to

```
ROUND((math+english+science)/3)
```

`AVG` is an aggregate function, it averages the values of all rows selected, or of all rows in a group when you use `GROUP BY`. If you just want the average of 3 columns in the same row, just add them and divide by the number of columns.

Comment: to what? is this the reason?

Comment: Ok! I get u, let me try

Comment: Thank u a lot Barmar, Your Genius